# AVCONV not working on heroku rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, avconv, buildpack

I have added AVCONV buildpack in my rails application but it is not working on Heroku. Here is a buildpack URL - https://github.com/mainameiz/avconv-buildpack

When i run '`heroku run bash`' and execute '`avconv`' command then get -

```
avconv: error while loading shared libraries: libmp3lame.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Same buildpack is working fine in my other heroku app

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have resolved the issue after struggling so many hours.

I need to set only `heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH= vendor/lib`

and it worked!!